# What resources are (technically) finite in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Most resources in Minecraft are infinite. Plants regrow, animals reproduce, mobs respawn. water sources can also become infinite, based on their placement. Even stone is infinite through the combination of flowing lava and water, and then smelting.

But there are some resources that do not have a natural "reproductive" quality. Eg, lava cannot replace another source block like water can.

What other resources in Minecraft do not have this quality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki category for non-renewable resources](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Category:Non-renewable_resources):

> ```
> Ancient Debris
> Block of Diamond
> Budding Amethyst
> Coal Ore
> Cobweb
> Conduit
> Copper Ore
> Dead Bush
> Deepslate (and derivatives)
> Diamond
> Diamond Ore
> Dragon Egg
> Dragon Head
> Elytra
> Emerald Ore
> Enchanted Golden Apple
> Enchantment Table
> Gold Ore
> Heart of the Sea
> Horse Armor (except leather)
> Iron Ore
> Jukebox
> Lapis Lazuli Ore
> Nether Quartz Ore
> Netherite and all Netherite-derived items
> Netherite block
> Netherrack
> Raw Copper
> Raw Gold
> Raw Iron
> Redstone Ore
> Sponge
> ```

Note that this list is not perfect; the original from the wiki contained some PE exclusive blocks (I have edited these out), and it may not contain all items from the 1.9 update of Minecraft. I have also removed items unobtainable in the survival mode inventory.

If you find any more, or feel that a block should be added/removed from the list, please feel free to edit this post.

Comment: Note that some of these are renewable when exploiting strange game mechanics, such as [Sand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2rshLa8Uw0), but counting those would be a bit silly.

Comment: It still contains the Stonecutter, which ***is* a PE exclusive**.

Comment: @John fixed. Also I believe it has been removed in one of the new versions of PE anyway.

Comment: If your going to invite others to freely edit to improve your answer, should it perhaps be a community wiki? I almost rejected a proposed edit because it aimed to strip a lot of items, stating that they were incorrectly listed.

Comment: With piglin bartering, dripstone-cauldron mechanics, azalea dirt-conversion, and regular trade, a lot of formerly non-renewable resources are now renewable. I've just removed all based on quartz, lava, gravel, glass, nether brick, soulsand and dirt.

Comment: @Gnemlock Good idea! I've made it a community wiki.